# Angularjs filter with nested json

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-filter

I have having trouble with filtering my table with the below json object.
It filters some of the key values, but doesnt work if my json is nested. 
I am sure i am doing something wrong and stupid.

heres a fiddle of the same. https://jsfiddle.net/pnypxhj8/1/

below is my JSON object:

```
[
 {
    "EmpId": "3901",   //----> Filter works on this
    "SubmitDate": "30/04/2017", //----> Filter works on this
    "Employee": "John", //----> Filter works on this
    "ProdRequest": [{
            "ProdName": "Mac Air laptop - Apple",
            "ManagersApproval": {
                "Status": "Approved",  //----> But Doesnt works on this
                "ManagersDetails": [{
                        "Name": "Steve Rock",
                        "Email": "steve.rock@test.com"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "Mary Nuts",
                        "Email": "mary.nuts@test.com"
                    }
                ],
                "Comments": ""
            },
            "AdminApproval": {
                "Status": "Pending",
                "AdminDetails": [{
                        "Name": "Hardy Lee",
                        "Email": "Hardy.Lee@test.com"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "Moss Grant",
                        "Email": "Moss.Grant@test.com"
                    }
                ],
                "Comments": ""
            },
            "RequestStatus": "Pending"
        },
        {
            "ProdName": "Note Book - Large",
            "ManagerApproval": {
                "Status": "Approved",
                "Approver": [{
                    "Name": "Jet Lee",
                    "Email": "jet.lee@test.com"
                }],
                "Comments": "Approved by Jet Lee"
            },

            "AdminApproval": {
                "Status": "Approved",
                "AdminDetails": [{
                        "Name": "Hardy Lee",
                        "Email": "Hardy.Lee@test.com"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "Moss Grant",
                        "Email": "Moss.Grant@test.com"
                    }
                ],
                "Comments": ""
            },
            "RequestStatus": "Completed"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "EmpId": "550",
    "SubmitDate": "22/04/2017",
    "Employee": "Mary Kom",
    "ProdRequest": [{
            "ProdName": "Seagate Harddisk 500TB",
            "ManagersApproval": {
                "Status": "Approved",
                "ManagersDetails": [{
                        "Name": "Steve Rock",
                        "Email": "steve.rock@test.com"
                    }
                ],
                "Comments": ""
            },
            "AdminApproval": {
                "Status": "Approved",
                "AdminDetails": [{
                        "Name": "Hardy Lee",
                        "Email": "Hardy.Lee@test.com"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "Moss Grant",
                        "Email": "Moss.Grant@test.com"
                    }
                ],
                "Comments": ""
            },
            "RequestStatus": "Approved"
        },
        {
            "ProdName": "Note Book - Large",
            "ManagerApproval": {
                "Status": "Approved",
                "Approver": [{
                    "Name": "Jet Lee",
                    "Email": "jet.lee@test.com"
                }],
                "Comments": "Approved by Jet Lee"
            },

            "AdminApproval": {
                "Status": "Approved",
                "AdminDetails": [{
                        "Name": "Hardy Lee",
                        "Email": "Hardy.Lee@test.com"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "Moss Grant",
                        "Email": "Moss.Grant@test.com"
                    }
                ],
                "Comments": ""
            },
            "RequestStatus": "Completed"
        }
    ]
}
```

]

Comment: Can you explain which data is not getting mapped and what you actually wanna achieve?

Comment: the data is getting mapped.. but its not getting filtered

"Status": "Approved",  //----> But Doesnt works on this

Comment: @nipiv if the answer is correct, could you mark as accepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: you have a typo on the object properties. You have `ManagerApproval` on filter but has `ManagersApproval` (with S) properties among your data.

Second: the filter should be `ng-repeat="a in data.ProdRequest | filter:{ProdName: prodName,  ManagerApproval: { Status: managerApproval }}"`

here's the working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pnypxhj8/3/